# Apache CXF WS-Security: Security processing failed (actions mismatch)

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm following this example to create a web service secured with signature only: https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/ws_security/sign_enc/src/main/java/demo/wssec/server/Server.java

This is what my code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FooService service = new FooService();
    String address = "http://localhost:1235/foo";
    EndpointImpl endpoint = (EndpointImpl) javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(address, service);

    Map<String,Object> inProps = new HashMap<>();
    inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature");

    inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, Server.class.getResource("./server_sign.properties"));
    inProps.put("signatureKeyIdentifier", "DirectReference");
    inProps.put("encryptionKeyTransportAlgorithm", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p");
    inProps.put("signatureAlgorithm", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1");

    endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps));}
```

When I send a soap messge to the server it throws an error:

```
org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
```

Also it shows the message

```
Security processing failed (actions mismatch)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: The service expects a signed measage. Could you pass the exception too? Is the received soap message signed?

Comment: Did you solve this?